# Use of concerning

Tags: word-choice, sentence-meaning, sentence-choice, sentence-usage

Which sentence sound more correct for business use?

“The company will deliver vital knowledge of system-related aspects concerning workflows to new employees.”

“The company will deliver vital knowledge of system-related aspects to new employees.”

When adding “concerning workflows” into the sentence, would it make the sentence sound wordies or weird ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the ell. Would you edit your first sentence? I cannot understand it completely. Also, you need to add more context to the question. Providing what you want to convey is a good start. You can do that by clicking on the edit icon.

Answer (score 1):

On the whole, it's an example of business gibberish, but if it is to be at least grammatical—here is my shot:

*The company will deliver **a** vital knowledge of system-related aspects of the **workflow** to new employees.*

1. Strange though it may seem, but ***an*** in-depth knowledge of the subject matter, **a** basic knowledge of computers, **a** detailed knowledge of criminal law and so on.
2. **workflow** is an uncountable noun
3. **aspect(s)** usually **of something** in this sense

Comment: _Knowledge_ doesn't need the indefinite article. One can _deliver knowledge_ about something, just as one can _deliver advice_ to someone.

Comment: With certain uncountable nouns - especially nouns referring to
human emotions and mental activity - we often use a/an when
we are limiting their meaning in some way.
We need a secretary with **a** first-class knowledge of
German. (**NOT ... with first-class knowledge of German.**)
She has always had **a** deep distrust of strangers.
That child shows **a** surprising understanding of adult
behaviour.
My parents wanted me to have **a** good education. (**NOT
... to have good education.**)

Answer (score 0):

This will largely be opinion-based, I think, but I prefer the second formulation. My rationale is that in the first sentence you have two descriptions of the knowledge that will be delivered in two different places-- the aspects will be system-related, and also they will concern workflows. I don't really know how to parse those out, so I assume that the aspects will be related to both systems and workflows. If that is the correct interpretation, then the wording is a bit awkward but not a real obstacle to understanding the sentence.

The presence of the second sentence suggests to me that the "concerning workflows" part is not really crucial to what you want to convey, and so the modest awkwardness from including it probably isn't worthwhile.